# java command line compilation

Tags: java, classpath

I have a simple, single file java program that relies on a single static jar.  The java code and the jar reside in the same directory.  For this one-off solution I don't want to bring in the weight of ant or maven, and just want to compile it directly.

On my dev box, the following compiles and runs my code fine:

```
javac -cp ".;dependency.jar" File.java
java -cp ".;dependency.jar" File
```

However, on my test box, the `java` command fails, and I get the following output:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class File
```

If I change my classpath arg to `-cp "."` I get the following output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dependency
```

My dev box is 64-bit Windows/Cygwin and java version `1.7.0_55`.  My test box is 64-bit Linux and java version `1.7.0_45`.

What is going wrong on my test box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The classpath separator character is different on Linux (and on Unix) than it is on Windows.  It's `;` on Windows, but it's `:` on Linux (and Unix).

Try this on Linux:

```
javac -cp ".:dependency.jar" File.java
java -cp ".:dependency.jar" File
```